# Getting error when trying to run a test with TestNG and WebDriverManager

Tags: java, selenium, webdrivermanager-java

I'm getting this error when trying to execute a test using TestNG and WebDriverManager. The dependency I'm using is the one mentioned in https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples for Maven, and the version of TestNG is 6.14.3.

My code is this simple:

```
private WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setupClass() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@AfterTest
public void teardown() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // Your test code here
}
```

And I get this error:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setupClass
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setConnectionManagerShared(Z)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:97)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:91)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:407)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:215)
at com.cuballama.automation.framework.Prueba.setupClass(Prueba.java:45)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest teardown
SKIPPED: test
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.setConnectionManagerShared(Z)Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder;
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:97)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:91)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:407)
at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:215)
at com.cuballama.automation.framework.Prueba.setupClass(Prueba.java:45)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at 
org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration, the example is using JUnit and you have switched to TestNG. You also updated the TestNG version from the github configuration 6.13. I checked with your version of TestNG,  that does not appear to be a problem.

```
package io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.test;

import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.*;

//import org.junit.After;
//import org.junit.Before;
//import org.junit.BeforeClass;
//import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

/**
 * Test with Chrome.
 *
 * @author Boni Garcia (boni.gg@gmail.com)
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public class ChromeTestNG {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setupClass() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }



    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Your test code here. For example:
//        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
//        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
//        By searchInput = By.id("searchInput");
//        wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(searchInput));
//        driver.findElement(searchInput).sendKeys("Software");
//        By searchButton = By.id("searchButton");
//        wait.until(elementToBeClickable(searchButton));
//        driver.findElement(searchButton).click();
//
//        wait.until(textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.tagName("body"),
//                "Computer software"));
    }

}
```

I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples.git
git clone https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager.git
download and install chromedriver 2.40
update Chrome version to 66
NOTE: I'm running on Ubuntu
```

Note: you can also un-comment the test code, it also worked for me

Comment: Thanks Boni.

I tried again with a simple test, even tried yours with no success. My error appears when the `chromedriver().setup()` is called. The error I see is the following:
`[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3`
`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".`
`SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation`
`SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

I also tried to add the Selenium Chromedriver dependency but no luck.

Comment: Who is Boni?
did you do this: git clone https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples.git ? Also, your SLf4j version is down rev from the example in github:
 <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the name. It's working now as I posted in an answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little bit more, I could find the cause of my problem. I was missing some dependencies in Maven.

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```